# Difference between .Net 4.0 framework and 4.5 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am presently working on an application with 3.5 framework. Would it be better to move the application to 4.0 or 4.5? What are the features/enhancements which are added in .NET 4.5 and not available in 4.0?

Any links to find the difference among both the versions(4.0 & 4.5) would be appreaciated.

Comment: [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing that's ***not*** in [.NET 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#net-45) is [support for Windows XP](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723735-make-net-4-5-work-on-any-os-that-supports-4-0).

So, if you want your application to support XP, you have to stay on .NET 4.0. :(

Answer (score 8):

.Net framework 4.5 has been officially released, so you may move to that instead of 4.0. One of the main thing I noticed new in .Net 4.5 is the support for Spatial data types. [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) and [DBGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeometry.aspx) and its support in new Entity framework 5.0

You may want to see: [What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

You may also see:

- .Net 4.5 came with C# 5.0. You may see its feature at: [Intro to C# 5.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/03/26/introduction-of-new-features-in-c-5-0.aspx)
- [The .NET Framework 4.5 includes new garbage collector enhancements for client and server apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx)
- [.Net 4.5 Version history from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5)
- [Cross-Platform Development with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)
- [Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx) : *(On 64-bit platforms, enables arrays that are greater than **2 gigabytes (GB)** in total size)*

Answer (score 3):

1. Background GC model for server processes
2. Async/await language feature in C#

[New framework features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

[New C# features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133817.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx

The inclusion of Entity Framework version 5 is working well for me.

Answer (score 2):

**-Asp.net 4.0**

- Web.config File Refactoring
- Extensible Output Caching
- Auto-Start Web Applications
- Permanently Redirecting a Page
- Shrinking Session State
- Expanding the Range of Allowable URLs
- Extensible Request Validation
- Object Caching and Object Caching Extensibility
- Extensible HTML, URL, and HTTP Header Encoding
- Performance Monitoring for Individual Applications in a Single Worker Process
- Multi-Targeting
  .... etc

**And Asp.net 4.5**

- there is also a long list of improvements.

  - Asynchronously Reading and Writing HTTP Requests and Responses
  - Improvements to HttpRequest handling
  - Asynchronously flushing a response
  - Support for await and Task-Based Asynchronous Modules and Handlers

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net) post for more info

Answer (score 0):

Read our Scott Hanselman blog

[**Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 is RELEASED - Here's 5 minute videos to get you up to speed quick**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012AndNETFramework45IsRELEASEDHeres5MinuteVideosToGetYouUpToSpeedQuick.aspx) 
.