# Downgrade from WPF 4.5 to 4.0 using in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After downgrade all references, packages and make sure the app still runs properly on .NET 4.5 PCs, when I try to run the app on a .NET 4.0 equipped PC, I still get the message:

"To run this application, you must first install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
.NETFramework, Version 4.5"

In order to check if every assembly was downgraded properly, I created a small console app to iterate over all assemblies and check

```
System.Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(item.FullName).ImageRuntimeVersion);
```

The result was the expected, only .net 4.0 or 2.0 assemblies.

I also checked app.config:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
```

The app runs fine on PCs with .NET 4.5, but it need to work on .NET 4.0 too.

What else could be missing?

Comment: There are significant [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12384794/1997232) between 4.0 and 4.5. If you have sources for 4.5 expect many changes before it's compilable for 4.0. And yes, you have to re-compile while [targeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) another (lower) framework version. Surprise?

Comment: The changes on code are done, the app targeting .net 4.0 runs properly (on .net 4.5 PCs). The hard work is done. My question is what might be missing if all assemblies are target to .net 4.0? Thank you.

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. Simply install the proper runtime, it's a binary replacement for 4.0 and 4.5. Whoever set up this PC had to install 4.0 by hand anyway, it wasn't part of *any* OS. Windows 78 came with 3.5, Windows 8 with 4.5. Downgrading only left you with an unsupported version on a PC that will be upgraded soon anyway

Comment: On the "problems that can kill your business due to 4.0" side, TLS 1.2 support was added in 4.5.2. Many service providers won't even allow TLS 1.1 for HTTPS connections anymore, which means you may not be able to connect using SSL to services soon (Google, partner services, the customer's own services)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the app.config. I had separate debug, release and stage configurations. When I downgrade the project on Visual Studio, it obviously downgraded only one of the app.config.

After manually fixing the sku to 4.0 the problem was gone.

Thank you!