# visual studio 2012 .net 4 created application requires .net 45

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, wpf-4.0

I have created a `WPF` application, using `Visual Studio 2012` running on `Windows 8` that targets `.NET 4`. But, when I try to run the app on another machine, that runs `Windows 7`, the app cannot starts. The target machine has installed `.NET 4`, but the app cannot run on it. But when I install the `.NET 4.5` on target machine, it works. I check the entire solution, and there is not any dependency to `.NET 4.5`. How is it possible? Any idea?

**UPDATE:** I'm using these packages:

1. Autofac.3.0.2
2. Autofac.WebApi.3.0.2
3. Caliburn.Micro.1.5.1
4. Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.1.5.0
5. EntityFramework.6.0.0-alpha3
6. gong-wpf-dragdrop.0.1.3.8
7. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0
8. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0
9. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost.4.0.20918.0
10. Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0
11. Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6
12. System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF.2.0.20525

While all of them are targeting to `.NET 4` in `package.config` file, is it any chance that one of them are using some `.NET 4.5` features?

Comment: Using ILMerge correctly can cause this problem.  "Cannot run on it" is not an error message, you'll need to quote the real one.

Comment: .Net 4.5 replaces .Net 4.0 once installed on a machine. You might want to refer to this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10492919/804797 to review differences and any possible breaking changes

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that no reference assembly  is targeted  to or code contains references to 4.5 framework. Then it should works

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem. I was compiling the project by `(Any CPU)` configuration. When I changed it to `x86`, the problem resolved.