# Targeting a higher framework than project’s current target framework

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm getting these build warnings.

`The referenced project 'X' is targeting a higher framework version (4.5) than this project’s current target framework version (4.0). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain.`

`The primary reference "C:\X\X.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".`

`This may lead to build failures.`

Does anyone knows Which kind of *failures*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can fail if the assembly you reference uses anything that was added in .NET 4.5 and didn't exist in 4.0. You can check the list of changes and additions, e.g. here: [Differences between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 in High level in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net)