# .NET app doesn't run on WinRT. Justify support for it in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, windows-runtime

I read that WinRT does not have a layer that support .NET applications here: seek to 1:55 seconds http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI0ABjSKAGU

I also read that .NET 4.5 framework provided support for Windows Runtime here [Differences between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 in High level in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net).

Here is my confusion:

Does that mean that I can run my .NET application on Windows Runtime now? How WinRT supports my .NET app? I have an idea that .NET can only be used to create web applications which are usually consumed using webbrowsers. If WinRT had a browser then why WinRT had problems in running my .NET application?

WinRT is an OS/layer which is installed on ARM based machines and tablets (Surface tablet).

I want to know what type of .NET application I will be developing for WinRT given that I now have support for Windows Runtime in .NET 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing an application for the Windows Store, you will be developing it using the Windows Runtime (WinRT). That is the only option today. After you've made that choice, you can choose between a C#/XAML or a HTML/WinJS user interface. You don't "choose" .NET 4.5. You're selecting the Windows Runtime.

There are two distinct platforms, and overlapping terminology:

**Windows Runtime** (usually abbreviated as WinRT) and **.NET**

The .NET platform has existed and been available for production development purposes since the release of Visual Studio 2002 and .NET 1.0. Using this platform, and its modern versions (4.5.1 with Visual Studio 2013), you can build what would be considered a traditional Windows executable or application. From Windows Services, desktop applications written for several different UI platforms (WinForms and WPF), and sophisticated web applications all can be created and are portable across all modern versions of Windows, with the exception of WindowsRT. WindowsRT runs traditionally on lower powered ARM processors, and cannot execute a traditional application written for .NET.

Unfortunately, the names and capabilities are very confusing. WinRT (Windows Runtime), which is the platform, can be used to create Windows Store applications. It cannot be used currently to build what would be considered a native desktop application. .NET 4.5 cannot be used to build a Windows Store application. The WinRT platform can target any modern Windows device, from tablet, to desktop. WinRT also runs on Windows RT, which are the lower powered, non-x86 chipsets like ARM.

All platforms share several languages: C#, VB, and C++.

The WinRT's libraries manifest as a layer that look identical to nearly identical in many cases to .NET libraries. In fact, the documentation can often be used for either in common cases. More confusingly, it's sometimes referred to as [.NET for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). You'll see how it's not a complete .NET 4.5 implementation.

The confusion often comes from the fact that they are so similar. The underlying code for WinRT is **not** .NET. It is opaque (and mostly written in C++). It looks like .NET 4.5, and often performs/behaves like .NET 4.5, but it isn't the same platform as is used by a traditional .NET 4.5 application. While you can create code that can run as a portable class library and use functionality and APIs that are common to all platforms (.NET and WinRT), a WinRT application can not directly call .NET 4.5 code.

The Windows Runtime is a highly sandboxed and API-curated developer experience, much like is available on various phone platforms, like the Windows Phone Runtime, iOS, and Android. If you look at the "surface" area of the .NET platform and CLR, you'll see how large and complex it has become, and that there are a lot of capabilities that either don't make sense in the context of a Windows Store application, or simply aren't safe. I expect over several releases Microsoft will include additional features to the Windows Runtime from the core Windows OS. Those APIs may/may not mirror similar functionality found in .NET 4.5.

However, on a Windows 8+ system, a Windows .NET application can access a subset of the APIs available in the WinRT (the marketing folks at Microsoft refer to it as a "streamlined" set of APIs). For example, you cannot access the WinRT UI platform and create a desktop application that builds its interface using WinJS or XAML, which are only available in a WinRT application.

[.NET Framework Support for Windows Store Apps and Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I watched this video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNJsr8rhP_M) few moments ago and it looks like this guy is using Visual Studio 2012 and he does none other setting than creating a new Windows Store app. Please tell me if he is using .NET 4.5 or not. Please seek to 28:00 minutes where he create a new Windows Store app by choosing a template from File Menu. And also I also read that .NET 4.5 framework provided support for Windows Runtime. What does it mean? I saw it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net)

Comment: Why did Microsoft provide support for Windows Runtime in .NET 4.5 if we cannot build applications for WinRT in .NET? This link says about the support: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net)

Comment: No, he is not using .NET 4.5 if he created a Windows Store application.

Comment: There are potentially useful APIs in the Windows Runtime that could be used by a .NET application -- so Microsoft exposed them.

Comment: What do I do if I want to build an application for Windows Runtime?

Comment: In Visual Studio, select one of the "Windows Store" project templates using the programming language you want to use.

Comment: WinRT APIs are exposed to create .NET Applications in metro style that cannot be deployed on WinRT. And we can create Windows Store application just like the way the guy is doing in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNJsr8rhP_M) video or the way you just said. Correct?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a little more detail. I'm not going to watch an hour long video ... looking at 28:xx, he creates a WinJS app, which uses JavaScript and the WinJS APIs to gain access to the Windows Runtime.