# What are .NET4 to .NET4.5 runtime changes

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

Eager to reduce risk in my project I would like to know what are the runtime changes between .NET4 to .NET4.5 (not 4.5.1 or 4.5.2)?

I could find runtime changes for 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 but not for 4.5.

Note: 
runtime changes for 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720774(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458360(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks!

**Update:** A Clarification: According to Microsoft runtime changes : may affect existing apps that target the previous versions of the .NET Framework but run on the .NET Framework 4.5.2\4.5.1\4.5 runtime

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net

Comment: @JacodeGroot thank you for your comment, but this Q&A describe what are the new features in .NET4.5 VS .NET4 and not runtime changes.

According to Microsoft runtime changes : may affect existing apps that target the previous versions of the .NET Framework but run on the .NET Framework 4.5.2\4.5.1\4.5 runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is an in place upgrade of .NET 4.0 and should be backwards compatible, although a few compatibility issues have been reported. Most of these changes do not require any programming modifications, see the link below for a full list of compatibility issues and their potential impact.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for your replay, this post according to Microsoft support points on breaking changes when re-targeting while i'm looking for the in-place changes. I'm planing to keep the code compiled targeting .net4 and just replace the runtime to 4.5.2. As I mentioned before, I wasn't able to find the runtime changed between .net4 to .net4.5.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0. When you install .NET 4.5 your .NET 4.0 assemblies in the \Windows\.NET Framework\V4.0.30319 are overwritten with a new set of assemblies. As long as you do no use any .net 4.5 functionality targeting the .net 4 and .net 4.5 framework is the same.